# Twist cobordisms in TQFT package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tqft

[image]

Is there a way to create twist cobordisms, cylinders which appear to cross over/under one another, using the TQFT tikz package?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Please post some code when asking a question - a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) - as that makes it much easier to help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can draw an overlapping pair of `cylinder to next` and `cylinder to prior`. The `at=(<coordinate>)` key is used to locate the starting point of the second cylinder at the point orthogonal to the first cylinder's end points.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{tqft}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  tqft/.cd,
  cobordism/.style={draw},
  every upper boundary component/.style={draw},
  every lower boundary component/.style={draw},
]
  \pic [tqft/cylinder to next,anchor=incoming boundary 1,name=c];
  \pic [tqft/cylinder to prior,anchor=incoming boundary 1,
          at=(c-outgoing boundary |- c-incoming boundary)];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Another day, another fascinating LaTeX package to discover...